# Changing JavaScript Font Size in Document Write

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, and it is doing what I want but I can't get any styling on it, and I was wondering how to do that? I've tried pointing CSS to the body but it still does nothing. My goal is to control the font size, the positioning, and the font colour. Please ignore the CSS call

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> SUCCESS</title>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SUCCESS.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keypress", function printer() 
{
document.write('SUCCESS');
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Styling is about html and css. How would you style it if you were given html and css only? Provide the static example.

Comment: don't use document.write unless you need to support a browser from the 90's :p

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` will accept HTML tags. Try something like this

```
document.write("<p style=''>Success</p>");
```

But I suggest you the better way is create an HTML element already with styles and change it according using `getElementById` or something

Answer (score 0):

So easy, use this javascript, look:

```
function CustomWrite(a,b) {
    b = '"'+b+'"';
    a = '<span style='+b+'>'+a+'</span>'
    return document.write(a);
}
```

how to use, look:

```
CustomWrite('SUCESS','you css code here');
```